# I want to put selected ,custom arrayList items to same type another ArrayList. I did it as follows, But it gives NullPoint exception

Tags: java, android, arraylist

This is my code. I want to select/filter array list items In arraylist toDOList. Then after that I want to add the selected items to toDoListCustom arraylist. I did it as follows. But it gives null point exception. todoList array Is not null. It contain values

```
/**
 * Created by Kasunka on 4/13/2015.
 */
public class LandingActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private String filterKey;
    static ArrayList<Fields> toDoList = null;
    static ArrayList<Fields> toDoListCustom = null;
    hyperOrder=10, partialOrder=4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing);

        initialize(); //initialize the layout

        ToDoObject asyTask = new ToDoObject();  // Run the Asyn task and retrieve the Custom ArralyList Object.
        asyTask.execute();// String URL here.
        try {
        toDoList = asyTask.get();  This get the arrayList<Fiels> from asyn task
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ToDoObjectCount toDoObjectCount = new ToDoObjectCount(toDoList);
        try {
            typeCount = toDoObjectCount.objectCount();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        toDo.setText("TO DO  "+typeCount[0]);
        red.setText("LATE\n"+lateOrders);
        green.setText(Integer.toString(greenOrder));
        yellow.setText(Integer.toString(yellowOrders));
        hyper.setText("Hyp\n"+typeCount[1]);
        partial.setText("PAT\n"+partialOrder);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        toDo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLAll);
        red = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLRed);
        green = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLGreen);
        yellow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLYellow);
        hyper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLHyper);
        partial = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLPartil);
        details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLDetails);

        toDo.setOnClickListener(this);
        yellow.setOnClickListener(this);
        hyper.setOnClickListener(this);
     }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bLAll:{
                filterKey = "all"; // pass the filter
                Intent todoListActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.TODOACTIVITY");
                Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();   // Create a Bundle and Put Bundle in to it
                bundleObject.putSerializable("key", toDoList);
                todoListActivity.putExtras(bundleObject); // Put Bundle in to Intent
                startActivity(todoListActivity);
            }break;
            case R.id.bLRed:{
                filterKey="red"; // pass the filter
                setCustomList(filterKey);                
            }break;
            case R.id.bLYellow:{
                filterKey="yellow";
            }break;
            case R.id.bLGreen:{
                filterKey="green";
            }break;
            case R.id.bLHyper:{
                filterKey="hyper";
                setCustomList(filterKey);
            }break;
            case R.id.bLPartil:{
                filterKey="partial";
            }break;
            case R.id.bLDetails:{
                filterKey="details";
            }

        }
    }

    private void setCustomList(String filterKey) {
        switch (filterKey){
            case "red":{

            }break;
            case "yellow":{

            }break;
            case "green":{

            }break;
            case "hyper":{
                for (int i=0; i<toDoList.size();i++){
                    if(toDoList.get(i).getIsHyper().contains("0")){
                          toDoListCustom.add(toDoList.get(i)); <-- I get error  here Null point Exception
                    }
                    startToDOactivity();
                }
            }break;
            case "partial":{

            }break;
        }
    }

    private void startToDOactivity() {
        Intent todoListActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.TODOACTIVITY");
        Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();   // Create a Bundle and Put Bundle in to it
        bundleObject.putSerializable("key", toDoListCustom);
        todoListActivity.putExtras(bundleObject); // Put Bundle in to Intent
        startActivity(todoListActivity);
    }
}
```

Asyn Task excute and return ArrayList And it is not null.

Comment: you need to create object `toDoListCustom = new ArrayList<Fields>();`

Comment: assign ArrayList<String> toDoListCustom = new ArrayList<String>();  and on click event selected item get in new string then put another ArrayList.add(string); that solve....

Comment: Thank you very much @amitsharma my issue is soleved.

Comment: @KZONE Great...You can upvote of my comment to get help some others

Comment: I'm new to this site. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate `toDoListCustom`:

```
static ArrayList<Fields> toDoListCustom = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

your second `arraylist`  (toDoListCustom) is `null` because you have not instantiate it.
instantiate it as

```
static ArrayList<Fields> toDoListCustom = new ArrayList<Fields>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written wrong code... I am trying to explain using number...

I have past your code below here...
(1) you have executed asynTask and in next line
(2) you are fetching the data from asynTask using ***asyTask*** object
You can't do like this because asynTask work in beck like a thread.
and in next line you are trying to fetch data from asynTask object.
as you know the working of thread is depend upon the CPU.
Your code and asynTask working parallel so you are getting null pointer exception.

You need to use **onPostExecute** method of **AsyncTask**, to do your task.
You need to write these below code in side **onPostExecute**.
You can pass the parameters of widget while you are executing AsyncTask and... use **onPostExecute** and do the operation from asyncTask only...

I think it would help you...

```
 ToDoObject asyTask = new ToDoObject();  // Run the Asyn task and retrieve the Custom ArralyList Object.
      (1)      asyTask.execute();// String URL here.
            try {
      (2)    toDoList = asyTask.get();  This get the arrayList<Fiels> from asyn task
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```